# MongoDB dump and restore

Tags: linux, mongodb, docker, mongodump, mongorestore

I installed the mongo using the docker, Now I need to take the **mongodb dump and restore**.

1) where can I download these two tools?
2) I don't need to install the complete mongo since the mongo is already installed using docker, I just need to download these two mongo tools and use the IP and PORT of docker mongo to dump and restore.

Thanks,
Harry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

MongoDB install this tool beside the core database so you can just execute commands inside the container or install `mongod` in your system and use this you can use below command to get MongoDB data:

```
docker exec <CONTAINER> sh -c 'exec mongodump --db somedb --gzip --archive' > dump_`date "+%Y-%m-%d"`.gz
```

also, you can get these utilities without mongo core. here is an example package for alpine-linux: [mongodb-tools](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/package/edge/community/x86_64/mongodb-tools). and for other distro you can make it yourself: [mongodb-tools](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-tools)

Comment: I agree that we can do using docker exec, but I need to connect to this docker from another machine, for this answer I provided an up vote 

Comment: @Harry so why not bring up another machine with only utilities you need to get exported data? I mean create a new mongodb on docker and use it for just export and imports.

Comment: thanks for your thought, but is there a way I get only the mongodump and mongorestore tools? So that i don't want to depend on docker in other machines

Comment: I will accept your answer, I have a clarification, How does the docker exec works for mongorestore ? docker exec f1d566 sh -c 'exec mongorestore --host 172.17.0.2 --port 27017 /home/test/mongo/dump_2019-02-03.gz' - This command is failing with the error : Failed: mongorestore target '/home/test/mongo/dump_2019-02-03.gz' invalid: stat /home/test/mongo/dump_2019-02-03.gz: no such file or directory